# Get the size of a Windows Store App when navigating to a page

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps, windows-8.1, visualstatemanager

So I recently upgraded and started updating my app for Windows 8.1  With the `AplicationViewState` being deprecated, I am having a problem getting the current size of the app to determine which layout should be loaded.  When I change the size of the app after the page is open, I am able to load the layout I need.  But when I navigate to the next page, it just loads the default view (which is landscape) no matter if the app is snapped or not.  I am subscribed to the `WindowSizeChanged` event to handle changes, but I cant seem to grab the size when first navigating to the page.

This is an example of how I am handling the size change inside the app

```
void WindowSizeChanged(object sender, WindowSizeChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Size.Width < e.Size.Height + 100)
        {
            VisualStateManager.GoToState(this, "Portrait", true);
        }

        else
        {
            VisualStateManager.GoToState(this, "Landscape", true);
        }
    }
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Thanks to whomever marked this down without providing any useful feedback!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out what I was doing wrong.  The `VisualStateMnager` on the xaml page was outside of the `grid control`.  Once I placed it into the `Grid Control` it worked just fine.